# Leaflet map is blurred or some parts are missing when printing the page to PDF in Firefox

Tags: firefox, leaflet

When using Firefox "Save to PDF" or "Microsoft print to PDF" features, a [leaflet](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet) map that is displaying fine in the browser will be blurred or have some parts missing in the resulting PDF file.

I tried to print to PDF the following minimal reproducible example of a leaflet map embedded in a website using Firefox and Edge's "Save to PDF" and "Microsoft print to PDF" Features.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Minimal reproducible example</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.css"
              integrity="sha256-p4NxAoJBhIIN+hmNHrzRCf9tD/miZyoHS5obTRR9BMY="
              crossorigin="">
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.js"
                integrity="sha256-20nQCchB9co0qIjJZRGuk2/Z9VM+kNiyxNV1lvTlZBo="
                crossorigin=""></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="map" style="width: 300px; height: 300px"></div>

        <script>
            var map = L.map('map').setView([51.5, 0], 7);
            var layer = L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                maxZoom: 19,
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
            }).addTo(map);
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

It displays as expected when using Edge "Save to PDF" or "Microsoft print to PDF" :

[image: Screenshot of the map outputted to the PDF by Edge. It looks fine.]

But when I use Firefox "Save to PDF" the result is blurred :

[image: Screenshot of the map outputted to the PDF by Firefox "Save to PDF" feature. It looks blurred]

And when I use Firefox "Microsoft print to PDF", the result is blurred and half of the map is missing :

[image: Screenshot of the map outputted to the PDF by Firefox "Microsoft print to PDF" feature. It looks blurred and the right half of the map is missing.]

What can I do to make it work as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a distinct difference in how PDF is integrated in Chrome, Edge and Firefox.

The distinction between Chrome and Edge browsers may depend which plug-in is active as Edge has one "Powered by Acrobat" or can use Chromium's PDFium (sourced from Foxit Software).

For "PDF Output" both Chrome and Edge for now, at least, use  Skia/PDF (Managed by Google).

Firefox uses a different image and HTML overlay method for rending PDF.js in the browser. However, that is not directly of issue here.

The output from save "HTML as PDF" in Edge/Chromium browsers is Skia PDF vectors with related tile images of PNG quality 256 x 256 pixels.
[image]

The output from Firefox print onto PDF is highly variable. It is a single image of embedment and output as a single lossy jpeg.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your insight! Do you have any idea for a fix? Maybe a Firefox plug-in?